# LeaseExpiredException: No lease error on HDFS (Failed to close file)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am trying to load large data into a dynamically partitioned table in HIVE.

I keep on getting this error. If I load data without partitioning, it works fine. If I work with smaller data set (with partition), it works fine as well. But for large dataset I start getting this error

The Error:

```
2014-11-10 09:28:01,112 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file 
/tmp/hive-username/hive_2014-11-10_09-25-26_785_2042278847834453465/_task_tmp.-ext-10002/
pseudo_element_id=NN%09/_tmp.000002_2

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException):
 No lease on /tmp/hive-username/hive_2014-11-10_09-25-26_785_2042278847834453465/_task_tmp.-ext-10002
/pseudo_element_id=NN%09/_tmp.000002_2: File does not exist. 
Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-737676454_1 does not have any open files.

at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:2445)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:2437)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.completeFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2503)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.completeFile(FSNamesystem.java:2480)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.complete(NameNodeRpcServer.java:535)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.complete(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:337)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44958)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1701)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1697)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1695)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1225)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
at $Proxy10.complete(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.complete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:330)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.
   java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
at $Proxy11.complete(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.completeFile(DFSOutputStream.java:1795)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.close(DFSOutputStream.java:1782)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.closeAllFilesBeingWritten(DFSClient.java:709)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.close(DFSClient.java:726)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.close(DistributedFileSystem.java:561)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.closeAll(FileSystem.java:2398)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$ClientFinalizer.run(FileSystem.java:2414)  
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when multiple mappers tries to access the same file.
Check your code for any bug which causes same file to be accessed simultaneously.This can also happen when a mapper access a file which is already deleted.

Answer (score 1):

set the option hive.exec.parallel=false and rerun the query.

Comment: Thanks. But I am still having the same problem.
 
Its a simple HIVE query, nothing complex.
 
insert overwrite table table1
partition(elementID)
select filename, elementID
from table2;
 
I am using hive-common-0.10.0-cdh4.3.0.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the no. of default allowed partitions per node and your job should be fine.

```
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=100000; 
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=100000;
```