# Why hdfs throwing LeaseExpiredException in Hadoop cluster (AWS EMR)

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, apache-tez

I am getting LeaseExpiredException in hadoop cluster -

**tail -f /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-ip-172-30-2-148.log**

> 2016-09-21 11:54:14,533 INFO BlockStateChange (IPC Server handler 10
>   on 8020): BLOCK* InvalidateBlocks: add blk_1073747501_6677 to
>   172.30.2.189:50010 2016-09-21 11:54:14,534 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server (IPC Server handler 31 on 8020): IPC
>   Server handler 31 on 8020, call
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.complete from
>   172.30.2.189:37674 Call#34 Retry#0: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException: No lease
>   on
>   /tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/1e4f71f0-9f29-468d-980e-9f19690bf849/.tez/application_1474442135017_0114/recovery/1/summary
>   (inode 26350): File does not exist. Holder
>   DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-143782605_1 does not have any open files.
>   2016-09-21 11:54:15,557 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange (IPC
>   Server handler 0 on 8020): BLOCK* allocate
>   blk_1073747503_6679{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null,
>   primaryNodeIndex=-1,
>   replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-86592ba7-c51a-431d-8019-9e362d721b28:NORMAL:172.30.2.189:50010|RBW]]} for
>   /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/hadoop/logs/application_1474442135017_0114/ip-172-30-2-122.us-west-2.compute.internal_8041.tmp

And, some of the hive query is also failing. I am guessing, it is because of above issue.

**tail -f /var/log/hive/hive-server2.log**

```
2016-09-21T11:59:35,126 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:execute(1477)) - Executing command(queryId=hive_20160921115934_c56d9c91-640b-4f5d-b490-34549a4258c7): 
INSERT INTO TABLE validation_logs 
SELECT 
"18364", 
"TABLE_VALIDATION",
error.code,
error.validator,
get_json_object(key, '$.table_name'),
NULL,
NULL,
error.failure_msg,
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20160921','yyyyMMdd')), 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())
FROM
(SELECT 
MAP(concat("{\"table_name\" : \"", table_name , "\"}"), error) AS err_map
FROM table_level_validation_result
) AS res
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(res.err_map) tmp AS key, error WHERE error IS NOT NULL AND (error.code="error" OR error.code="warn")

2016-09-21T11:59:35,126 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(1054)) - Query ID = hive_20160921115934_c56d9c91-640b-4f5d-b490-34549a4258c7
2016-09-21T11:59:35,126 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(1054)) - Total jobs = 1
2016-09-21T11:59:35,127 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(1054)) - Launching Job 1 out of 1
2016-09-21T11:59:35,127 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:launchTask(1856)) - Starting task [Stage-1:MAPRED] in serial mode
2016-09-21T11:59:35,127 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: tez.TezSessionPoolManager (TezSessionPoolManager.java:canWorkWithSameSession(404)) - The current user: hadoop, session user: hadoop
2016-09-21T11:59:35,127 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: tez.TezSessionPoolManager (TezSessionPoolManager.java:canWorkWithSameSession(421)) - Current queue name is null incoming queue name is null
2016-09-21T11:59:35,173 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: ql.Context (Context.java:getMRScratchDir(340)) - New scratch dir is hdfs://ip-172-30-2-148.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/hive/hadoop/65cf7f02-a7d3-40ba-a93f-ff5214afbdfc/hive_2016-09-21_11-59-34_474_5003281239065359634-127
2016-09-21T11:59:35,174 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: exec.Task (TezTask.java:updateSession(279)) - Session is already open
2016-09-21T11:59:35,175 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:createLocalResource(758)) - Resource modification time: 1474459142291 for hdfs://ip-172-30-2-148.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/85d36c12-c629-44a8-b23c-c628898a79b7/commons-vfs2-2.0.jar
2016-09-21T11:59:35,176 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:createLocalResource(758)) - Resource modification time: 1474459142320 for hdfs://ip-172-30-2-148.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/85d36c12-c629-44a8-b23c-c628898a79b7/emr-ddb-hive.jar
2016-09-21T11:59:35,177 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:createLocalResource(758)) - Resource modification time: 1474459142353 for hdfs://ip-172-30-2-148.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/85d36c12-c629-44a8-b23c-c628898a79b7/emr-hive-goodies.jar
2016-09-21T11:59:35,178 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:createLocalResource(758)) - Resource modification time: 1474459142389 for hdfs://ip-172-30-2-148.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/85d36c12-c629-44a8-b23c-c628898a79b7/emr-kinesis-hive.jar
2016-09-21T11:59:35,178 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:createLocalResource(758)) - Resource modification time: 1474459142423 for hdfs://ip-172-30-2-148.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/85d36c12-c629-44a8-b23c-c628898a79b7/hive-contrib-2.1.0-amzn-0.jar
2016-09-21T11:59:35,179 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: tez.DagUtils (DagUtils.java:createLocalResource(758)) - Resource modification time: 1474459142496 for hdfs://ip-172-30-2-148.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/hive/hadoop/_tez_session_dir/85d36c12-c629-44a8-b23c-c628898a79b7/hive-plugins-0.0.1-emr-upgrade-20160919.070538-1.jar
2016-09-21T11:59:35,179 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: exec.Task (TezTask.java:build(321)) - Dag name: INSERT INTO TABLE valid...error.code="warn")(Stage-1)
2016-09-21T11:59:35,180 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3883([])]: ql.Context (Context.java:getMRScratchDir(340)) - New scratch dir is hdfs://ip-172-30-2-148.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/hive/hadoop/65cf7f02-a7d3-40ba-a93f-ff5214afbdfc/hive_2016-09-21_11-59-34_474_5003281239065359634-127
2016-09-21T11:59:35,223 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3881([])]: impl.YarnClientImpl (YarnClientImpl.java:submitApplication(273)) - Submitted application application_1474442135017_0147
2016-09-21T11:59:35,224 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3881([])]: client.TezClient (TezClient.java:start(477)) - The url to track the Tez Session: http://ip-172-30-2-148.us-west-2.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1474442135017_0147/
2016-09-21T11:59:35,391 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3429([])]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(1054)) - Map 1: 0(+0,-4)/1  
2016-09-21T11:59:35,446 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3429([])]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printError(1063)) - Status: Failed
2016-09-21T11:59:35,447 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-3429([])]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printError(1063)) - Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1474442135017_0134_2_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1474442135017_0134_2_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1474442135017_0134_2_00_000000_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:160)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:152)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:172)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:203)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:818)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.open(S3NativeFileSystem.java:1193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:771)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.open(EmrFileSystem.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:297)
    ... 20 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1474442135017_0134_2_00_000000_1:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:160)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:152)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:172)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:203)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:818)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.open(S3NativeFileSystem.java:1193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:771)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.open(EmrFileSystem.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:297)
    ... 20 more
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1474442135017_0134_2_00_000000_2:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:160)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:152)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:172)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:203)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:818)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.open(S3NativeFileSystem.java:1193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:771)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.open(EmrFileSystem.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:297)
    ... 20 more
], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1474442135017_0134_2_00_000000_3:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:160)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://data-platform-insights/data-platform/internal_test_automation/2016/09/21/18364/logs/validations/table_col_aggregate_validation_result/.hive-staging_hive_2016-09-21_11-57-58_703_5106478639780932144-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000000_0.gz'
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:152)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:172)
    ... 14 more
```

**Hive logs with DEBUG mode enabled -**

Highlighted exceptions in green color.

As per my understanding, just before exception, it replaced file name to some other name, and all these happens in S3. Since, S3 is eventual consistent, thats why sometimes it shows this exception,and sometimes it worked file.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cwXVqQ3p-xPFcBqU9AuD7C8z8rHjhUIHwPjY-nVpFK0/edit?usp=sharing

Also set hive configuration properties before executing the query -

```
set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize = 2000000000
set mapreduce.map.speculative = false
set mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress = true
set hive.exec.compress.output = true
set mapreduce.task.timeout = 6000000
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge = true
set io.compression.codecs = org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCode
set hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join.noconditionaltask = false
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin = true
set hive.exec.compress.intermediate = true
set hive.enforce.bucketmapjoin = true
set mapred.output.compress = true
set mapreduce.map.output.compress = true
set hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join = false
set hive.auto.convert.join = false
set mapreduce.reduce.speculative = false
set mapred.output.compression.codec = org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
set hive.cache.expr.evaluation=false
set mapred.output.compress=true
set hive.exec.compress.output=true
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
set io.compression.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
set hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true
set mapreduce.map.output.compress=true
set hive.auto.convert.join=false
set mapreduce.map.speculative=false
set mapreduce.reduce.speculative=false
```

**Cluster details -**

1. one Data-node with 32 GB disk space.
2. Hive - 2.1.0, execution engine - tez 0.8.3
3. hadoop - 2.7.2

**Questions-**

1. Why it is throwing LeaseExpiredException ?
2. IS Hive query failure related to LeaseExpiredException ?
3. Is it because of wrong hive configuration properties ?

**Update-1**

As per this answer - [LeaseExpiredException: No lease error on HDFS (Failed to close file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842933/leaseexpiredexception-no-lease-error-on-hdfs-failed-to-close-file),

I added

```
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=100000; 
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=100000;
```

But then also showing the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue. Let me explain in detail.

Exceptions that is coming -

1. LeaveExpirtedException - from HDFS side.
2. FileNotFoundException - from Hive side (when Tez execution engine executes DAG)

**Problem scenario-**

1. We just upgraded the hive version from 0.13.0 to 2.1.0. And, everything was working fine with previous version. Zero runtime exception.

**Different thoughts to resolve the issue -**

1. First thought was, two threads was working on same piece because of NN intelligence. But as per below settings

   set mapreduce.map.speculative=false
   set mapreduce.reduce.speculative=false

that was not possible.

2. then, I increase the count from 1000 to 100000 for below settings -

   SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=100000; 
   SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=100000;

that also didn't work.

3. Then the third thought was, definitely in a same process, what mapper-1 was created was deleted by another mapper/reducer. But, we didn't found any such logs in Hveserver2, Tez logs.
4. Finally the root cause lies in a application layer code itself. In hive-exec-2.1.0 version, they introduced new configuration property

   "hive.exec.stagingdir":".hive-staging"

Description of above property -

> Directory name that will be created inside table locations in order to
>   support HDFS encryption. This is replaces ${hive.exec.scratchdir} for
>   query results with the exception of read-only tables. In all cases
>   ${hive.exec.scratchdir} is still used for other temporary files, such
>   as job plans.

So if there is any concurrent jobs in Application layer code (ETL), and are doing operation(rename/delete/move) on same table, then it may lead to this problem.

And, in our case, 2 concurrent jobs are doing "INSERT OVERWRITE" on same table, that leads to delete metadata file of 1 mapper, that is causing this issue.

Resolution -

1. Move the metadata file location to outside table(table lies in S3).
2. Disable HDFS encryption (as mentioned in Description of stagingdir property.)
3. Change into your Application layer code to avoid concurrency issue.

Related question - [Why hive_staging file is missing in AWS EMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547001/why-hive-staging-file-is-missing-in-aws-emr/39715837#39715837)